# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: vb.net

i have been getting this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." on a code that previously worked untill i migrated the database to a 2008 server.

Here is the code;

```
  query1 = "INSERT INTO RequisitionSummary (RequisitionDate, RequisitionAmount, IssuingAmount) VALUES('" & dtpRequisitionDate.value & "','" & txtRequisitionAmt.Text & "','" & txtIssuingAmount.Text & "')"
```

I will appreciate if the error can be spotted because i have tried different approaches including converting the value in a variable befor inserting.

Thanks
Nelson

Comment: Warning! Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: What does `dtpRequisitionDate.value` contain when you get the error? Why are you not using a [paremeterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) which would not have this kind of problem to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

depending on the regional setting of your server vs your computer, you will get this error if it does not match.

- You might need to convert into a `date` and then apply a formatting to be sure it match the setting in your database.
- Or you can make a SQL Convert to regional setting in the sql (look at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for more details on convert)